GCP function sslv3 alert handshake failure
I have this GCP function deployed which was smoothly working until last week. This week though, it started to trow this ssl error when it goes trough this code:
import httpx

with httpx.Client(follow_redirects=True, http2=True, verify=True) as client: 
    response = client.get('https://portalibre.fgv.br/calendario-de-divulgacao')
    print(response.status_code)

error: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1000)
A few details I might add:

GCP logs the timestamp of this error being +3hours from the timezone of the website source url
I've tested the same code on Google Colab environment, it shows me the same timestamp of the GCP function, and it somehow works just fine
I'm repeating myself, but this code was running perfectly last week.

